# Central Limit Theorem and Law of Large Numbers for stable linear stochastic systems

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

I am new to Markov chain in continuous state space. It would be great if anyone can help me with this.

Consider a linear stochastic system: $x_{t+1}=Ax_t +w_t$, where $w_t$ i.i.d. Gaussian with zero mean, finite variance. Suppose $A$ is stable, i.e. the spectral norm is less than 1. Then, we know this Markov chain has time-invariant distribution $\pi$.

My question is, does central limit theorem (CLT) and strong law of large numbers (LLN) hold? In particular, CLT means, for any function $f(\cdot)$, there exists $\sigma>0$, such that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt T} \sum_{t=1}^T f(x_t) \to N(\mathbb E_{\pi} f(x), \sigma^2$$
where the convergence is in distribution;
and LLN means
$$\frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^T f(x_t) \to \mathbb E_{\pi} f(x)$$
where the convergence is almost surely.

Thank you very much!